# ui-grid: How to use function for columnDefs

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

For some reason I need to create headers dynamically because of component I used.

So I have a function which and that function I want to use to provide values to columnDefs

```
ctrl.getColumnDefs = () => {
    let columns = []
    if (name === 'deamon') {
        var normalCol = {
          field: 'name',
          enableSorting: true,
          cellTooltip: (row, col) => row.entity[col.field],
          enableCellEdit: false
        };

    return columns.push(normalCol);
}
```

Then I am using

```
ctrl.grid = {
 columnDefs: getColumnDefs() 
}
```

Which is throwing `TypeError: self.options.columnDefs.forEach is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the value of **push**. That returns the new length of the array as per docs [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp).

You probably want to return **columns** instead of push.

Probably you want this

```
columns.push(normalCol)
return columns
```